# Finite subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ and $\mathrm{O}(n)$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups, computer-algebra

> Question 1:Is there a reference that lists all possible finite subgroups and their orders of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ and $\mathrm{O}(n)$ for $n=4$ or even higher $n$ over the real numbers?

I can only find incomplete lists on wikipedia, mathoverflow or other sources in the internet.

> Question 2: Is there a computer algebra package that can list those finite subgroups up to some order? Maybe a package of GAP?

Comment: I think I asked question 1 of Ed Swartz (Cornell) once, and he knew of a Ph.D thesis where the complete list was given.  Unfortunately I forget the reference, but perhaps try contacting Ed.

Comment: All positive integers appear as orders of cyclic subgroups of orthogonal groups, so perhaps Question 1 should be made more fine-grained.  For $n=4$, you can make a list of finite order subgroups using the product decomposition of $Spin(4)$ and the $n=3$ case.

Comment: @S.Carnahan You are right. I changed the question so that it asks for the groups now.

Comment: Tangentially relevant: there's a discussion of subgroups of $SO(4)$ that act freely on $S^3$ in Scott's *The geometries of 3-manifolds*. I don't know if anyone has written *The geometries of 3-orbifolds*, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finite subgroups of $\operatorname{SO}(4)$ and $\operatorname{O}(4)$ are enumerated in Chapter 4 of the book:

*Conway, John H.; Smith, Derek A.*, **On quaternions and octonions: their geometry, arithmetic, and symmetry**, Natick, MA: A K Peters (ISBN 1-56881-134-9/hbk). xii, 159 p. (2003). [ZBL1098.17001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1098.17001).

There may be results for some $n>4$, but since every finite group has faithful orthogonal representations, this gets hopeless at some point.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [table here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/R.html#dim4+) of all groups of order up to 500 with a 4-dimensional faithful orthogonal irreducible representation. This is almost the same thing as a subgroup of $O(4)$, but you'd also need to think about the reducible case.

Comment: This misses the most important ones (e.g., the perfect one of order $2.60^2=7200$).